# Clicking on Hidden Menu Item in Selenium 2.33 Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a Menu Element that pops down only when clicked and then fades out on losing focus. My task is to click on a hidden sub menu item.
From previous answers to similar situations I used the following code to click on the Sub menu Items.

```
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 WebElement mainMenuElement= driver.findElement(By.id("Mainmenu"));
 builder.moveToElement(mainMenuElement).build().perform();
 mainMenuElement.click();
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 WebElement mySubMenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Kit Components']"));
 mySubMenu.click();
```

But, when I run the code in chrome v 27, once in three times or so the submenu item never gets clicked. The mainmenu opens up and stays still forever. But the submenu.click() is executed everytime without Exceptions and the submenu is also visible.

Is this because of my code? or
Could this be because the Submenu item has a localized region for Click? i.e Manually when I click on the submenu, the click works only on the text and not on remaining blank regions of the element.

Im using selenium 2.33 Java with chrome v 27.

Any advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please, don't use `Thread.sleep` in your code. *Ever*. Instead, use the [`FluentWait` or `WebDriverWait` commands](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).

Now, to answer your question, it seems as if you have stumbled upon what some people call a "flapper", or a "flakey test". If your test fails one in three times or so, something is really flakey.

I have noticed every once in a while that the click function doesn't always do the actual click (even though every indication in the code says it did). I wonder if you're happening upon this? Usually I do a check to see if the click seems to happen. If it tried clicking in the code but nothing happens, I will let it retry the click. If the retry doesn't work, then something is really up.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I figured the click doesn't work whenever I leave the mouse pointer inside the webpage..now I'm using JscriptExecutor to click. its working fine till now.